# Function that counts chars in a string in C

Tags: c, string

I am new a C. I would like to get help to finish my function.

The mission is:

Write a function that accepts a string `maximum length of 256 characters containing characters from 'a' to 'z'`.

The function to print the number of occurrences of each character.

For example: input `abba` output will be:

```
a = 2 b = 2 c = 0 d = 0 .... z = 0
```

Do not use if during any function.

I would like to get your help to finish this program please.

This is my code

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#define size 256



void repeat(char *str);
void main()
{
    char str[size];
    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    flushall;
    gets(str);
    repeat(str);
    system("pause");
    return ;
}
void repeat(char *str)
{

    char temp=strlen(str);
    int i, count=0;
    do
    {
    for (i=0; i<temp ; i++)
        {
            count += (*str == str[temp-i]);
        }
    printf("Char %c appears %d times\n ",*str,count);
    count=0;
    }
    while(*(str++));
}



    Please enter a string:
abbba
Char a appears 1 times
 Char b appears 2 times
 Char b appears 1 times
 Char b appears 0 times
 Char a appears 0 times
 Char   appears 0 times
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

this is the output!
I would like to do it in the same building i did.
and should be like
Char a appears 2 times
Chars b appears 3 times

Comment: Can you explain what problems you are currently having ? Does the code compile ? Does it run ? If so, how is the output different from what you expect >

Comment: `gets()` is evil, deprecated from the standard library, and every time its is used, somewhere a kitten dies. Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: This should work perfectly. Tell us the problem you are facing while executing it.

Comment: Did you use the **debugger** to step through your code, inspect the variables and compare them with what you expect?

Comment: I suspect the idea of the assignment was to do `counts[*str - 'a']++`.

Comment: Hey guys! i just edit my post! The code is running but i am having problems with the output. it's doesn't work like i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** I have edited the program to follow the requirements of @SagiBinder.

(In my old version, I used an `if` sentence that checked if the character is in the set 'a'...'z').

The type of `temp` must be "bigger", that is, something different to `char`.
Try `int`, instead.

The algorithm would be this (some details of your program are not repeated here):

```
int temp = strlen(str);

int i, j;

unsigned char c; 

int ch[UCHAR_MAX]; // The macro CHAR_MAX needs the header <limits.h>
for (i = 1; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++)
    ch[i] = 0;

for (j=0; j<temp ; j++) {
      c = (unsigned char)(str[j]);
      ch[c]++;
}

for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    printf("%c == %d\n", c, ch[c]);
```

The variable `temp` holds the length of the string `str`.
The macro `UCHAR_MAX` (existing in the header `<limits.h>`, that you have to `#include` at the beginning of the program). It is the max. value that holds in a `unsigned char`.
The array `ch[]` contains a component for each possible value in the range of the type `unsigned char`. The intent is that, for some character `c`, the element `ch[c]` is the amount of times that `c` is in `str`.
I have used `unsigned char` in order to ensures that the index `c` of the array `ch[]` when writting `ch[c]` is a non-negative integer value, because an array cannot have negative indexes.
The 2nd `for` goes through the string `str`. In the step number `j`, the `j`-th character of the string `str` is taken.
This character is a value of type `char`.
Since one cannot be sure that `char` have not negative values, I have converted it to `(unsigned char)` with an explicit cast.
This value is held in the variable `c`.

The value of `c` has the (`unsigned char` version of the) j-th character in `str`, 
so we are going to count it.
How?
Well, we access the array of counters: `ch[]` with index `c`, and increment its value in 1:

```
      ch[c]++;
```

After the `for` is finished, we have in the array `ch[]` the information we want.

Finally, we check for the characters from `'a'` to `'z'`.
(For this, we have supposed that the character encodings in our system follow the convention that the letters have **contiguous** values).

The 3rd `for` goes from `'a'` to `'z'`, and the values of the letter (the variable `c` that controls the `for`) and the counting of this letter, that is, `ch[c]`.

Moreover: to show the count of any character, you need a re-cast to `char`, in this way:

```
    printf("%c: %d\n", (char)c, ch[c]);
```

But this is not necessary with the letters 'a' to 'z', because they belong to the **basic execution character set** which means that their values are non-negative and equal to their `unsigned char` counterparts. So, in this case, it is enough to write:

```
    printf("%c: %d\n", c, ch[c]);
```

---

**EDIT 2:** I will use the idea in the answer of **@jxh** to improve my code.

Since it cannot be guaranted that the encodings of letters 'a' to 'z' are in contiguous order, we can use a string holding the letters:

```
   char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

The "last" element is, by **C** convention, a \0 character held after the element 'z'.

```
   Now, we can show the letter counting by changing the 3rd `for` in this way:  

 for (i = 0; letter[i] != '\0'; i++)
     printf("%c == %d\n", letter[i], ch[letter[i]]);
```

This is equivalent to write:

```
 for (i = 0; letter[i] != '\0'; i++) {
     c = letter[i];
     printf("%c == %d\n", c, ch[c]);
 }
```

Comment: Hey pablo! I would like to get more details about the letter "   letter[str[i]-'a'] ++;" I didn't understand it. Thanks for your help

Comment: str[i] is the character you want to increment.  If you convert a character to a string, 'a' is 97.  The lowercase alphabet runs from 97..122.  You could make a bigger array (letter[123] or letter[256]), or you just subtract 97 from each char before using it in the array.  A common way to do that is to subtract 'a', which provides a little bit of a hint why you're subtracting a constant, rather than just a magic number.

Comment: I need do this function without using the IF i am talking about the second FOR

Comment: @SagiBinder: I have changed my answer by writting a clearer version of the program. It is more technical too. Observe that, in order to avoid my first version (that used an "if" there), it is necessary to consider an array that counts over all the possible characters in the system. The idea is to use the character itself as an index of an array of counters. Each character has, in this way, its own counter, easily accessed. The problem with this approach is that some `char` values could be negative. This need a temporary conversion to `unsigned char`, that I have used in my program.

Answer (score 3):

You make a stipulation about not using `if`. This satisfies that restriction.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, c;
    int counts[256] = { 0 };
    const char lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        counts[c] += 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; lower[i]; ++i) {
        c = lower[i];
        printf("Char %c appears %d times.\n", c, counts[c]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your attempt is that you do not track any state to remember which characters you have already printed information about. It also fails to include the character under consideration as part of the count. It also makes multiple passes over the string to collect count information about each character, but that doesn't affect correctness, just performance. If you can somehow remember which character you have already printed out information for, so that you don't do it again when the same character appears later in the string, your method should print out the counts for the characters that appear. Afterwards, you would need to print out zero counts for the characters that did not appear at all. If the outputs need to be in alphabetical order, then you need to make sure you take care of that as well.

One way to track the information properly and to allow your output to be printed in alphabetical order is to maintain counts for each character in an array. After making a pass over the string and incrementing the count associated with each found character, you can iterate over the count array, and print out the counts.

---

The following program is for zubergu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int i, c;
    int counts[26] = { 0 };
    const char lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case 'g':
        case 'h': case 'i': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case 'm': case 'n':
        case 'o': case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case 't': case 'u':
        case 'v': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
            counts[strchr(lower, c) - lower] += 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; lower[i]; ++i) {
        printf("Char %c appears %d times.\n", lower[i], counts[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you initialize `counts` to all `\0`? It's an array `int`s, why not set the elements to `0` rather than the NULL character? You can even initialize the array at definition with `int counts[256] = {0};`.

Comment: @Gauthier: The `memset()` sets all bits to `0`. The compound initialization is also valid, but some compilers (erroneously) warn about not providing enough intializers.

Comment: @zubergu: My program doesn't care what value `'a'` is, it works with either ASCII or EBCDIC encodings.

Comment: @zubergu: The array is sized to `256`.

Comment: I went lost while i was trying to read this code. I don't know what is EDF and i know only malloc for memory.. thanks anyway

Comment: @SagiBinder: `EOF` is the return code returned by `getchar()` when there is no more input. I only allocate memory using an array, just like you did with `str` in your program.

Comment: @jhx my bad, confused counts with lower somehow. Still, terrible waste of space, keeping array of 256 elements to use 26 of them.

Comment: @zubergu: For portability, you cannot assume the alphabetical letters are contiguously numbered. This is only true for the numeric digits. So, the logic to track the state in 26 counters is a little more complicated than simply `counts[letter - 'a']`. I am guilty for not worrying about an extra 230 bytes begin wasted in a program that is probably going to occupy a few kilobytes in RAM anyway.

Comment: The `memset()` does set all bits to 0, but why write the NULL character to `int`s? It works but it's not logical. Why initialize `int`s used to count number of occurrences with a `char`, even if it works?

Comment: @Gauthier: `memset()` is generic, and it takes the size as the number of bytes (which is what `sizeof()` returns). It sets each byte to the value provided in the second parameter, and a `char` literal is the traditional way to represent the value passed to `memset()`.

Comment: @jxh I get what's your code doing, and why. Just wondering about something that will not take 10x space it could.

Comment: @zubergu: I am not saying it isn't possible, it will just take more code, and more compute, and so it would actually be more complicated than what I have written.

Comment: I understand that the second parameters often takes a `char`, and the value of doing "as usual". The prototype of `memset()` tells us the parameter is an `int` (later converted to `unsigned char` within `memset()`, agreed). It's a detail, really, but I thought unexperienced programmers would find it confusing.

Comment: @Gauthier: Okay, I buy your clarity point. I changed the initialization to use the `{ 0 }` initializer.

Comment: @zubergu: 26 element array of counts just for you.

Comment: @jxh thanks, that looks great, appreciate it and will learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be one of the ugliest solutions, but also the simplest:

```
while(*str!='\0')
{
  switch(tolower(*str))
  {
    case 'a': a_count++;break;
    case 'b': b_count++;break;
    .
    .
    .
  }
  str++;
}
```

It checks if str points to valid letter, then turns it to lower, so it's not case sensitive('A' will be same as 'a' character). No 'if' used and will work with every length char array terminated with '\0' char.

Comment: Not every piece of code has to be clever. It's even more true if you are just a beginner. Better use simple, understandable for you piece of code, than copy somebody else's  fast, clever solution and not get a word out of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Optimized solution. complexity O(N)**, N - Input String length.

your void repeat function will be like this,

```
void repeat(char *str)
{

    int temp=strlen(str);// use int here
    int i, count=0;
int charCount[26] = {0};


#if 0
//your logic, traverses the string (n*n) time, n - input string length.
    do
    {
        for (i=0; i<temp ; i++)
        {
            count += (*str == str[temp-i]);
        }
        printf("Char %c appears %d times\n ",*str,count);
        count=0;
    }
    while(*(str++));
#endif

#if 1
// This logic traverses string once only. n time, n - input string length.
for (i=0; i<temp ; i++)
    {
        charCount[str[i]%'a']++;
    }

for (i=0; i<26 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c appears :  %d times \n", 'a'+i, charCount[i]);
    }
#endif
}
```

[EDIT]
Here

```
charCount[str[i]%'a']++; // 'a' is used a its ASCII Value.
```

You can use it as

```
charCount[str[i]%97]++;
```

1. If you wan to count lower case letter and upper case letter both.

use it like this

```
if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
        iMap = str[i]%97; // 97 is ASCII Value of 'a'
        charCount[iMap]++;
    }else if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
        iMap = str[i]%65; // 65 is ASCII Value of 'A'
        charCount[iMap]++;
    }
//iMpa is a integer (int iMap;), used for better undersanding.
```

Comment: It's looks good and working but I would like to get help what does this "charCount[str[i]%'a']++;" in the code?

Comment: I just updated the code, It will count only abcd letters. It will ignore space, comma etc.

Comment: I tired to build some input checks will be between 'a' to 'z' to solve this problem but i went lost with it.

Comment: #define size 256

void repeat(char *str);
void main()
{
 int i;
 char str[size]; // Setting a string up to 256 characters
 printf("Please enter a string:\n");
 flushall;
 gets(str); // Getting the string
/* while(*str) // Checking the string is based of chars between 'a' untill 'z'
 {
  for (i=0 ; i<strlen(str) ; i++ )
  {
   if ((strchr(str,str[i]) > 'a') && (strchr(str,str[i]) < 'z'))
    str++;
   else {
   printf("Input error, The string must contain characters from 'a' to 'z'\n");
   return;
    }
  }
 }*/
 repeat(str);// Calling the counting fucntion
 system("pause");
 return ;
}

Comment: The updated code is worst. You cannot use all that **%** thing. It brings bad results.

Answer (score -1):

```
 i = 0;
  while (s[i] !=0)
   if (( s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] <= 'A' && s[i] >= 'Z'))
   {
     letters++;
     i++;
   }
   else
     if (( s[i] >= '!' && s[i] <= ')'))
     {
       other++;
     }
   else
     if (( s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
     {
       numbers++;
     }
      total = letters + numbers + other;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the task given bcause it doesn't discriminate different letters.

Comment: And it does not fulfill "Do not use if during any function".